# Why won't my uitextfield open the keyboard on touch?

Tags: ios, uitableview

For some reason, the search field in my section header cannot be selected in order to bring up the keyboard. Also, nothing appears on my table view cells, and I'm not sure why. My code is below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];  

  self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

  self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
  self.tableView.delegate = self;
  [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
  [self.searchField resignFirstResponder];

  return NO;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return 8;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  return 60;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

  UIView *customHeader = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];

  // Add search field
  UITextField *field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 20, 250, 50)];
  field.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
  field.delegate = self;
  [customHeader addSubview:field];

  return customHeader;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  NSString *cellIdentifier;

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    NSLog(@"i am here");

    UITextField *field = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 20, 250, 50)];
    field.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    field.delegate = self;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:field];
  }

  return cell;
}
```

Comment: Do you specify header height of your tableview? Make sure you have – tableView:heightForHeaderInSection: and that for the section where you have search bar return 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it does not work because you do not specify header height for that section. You should have something like

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return 50.0;
}
```

If you have more than one section make sure, you do this only for the desired section.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use nib-files or storyboard? According to apple documentation if you cannot load the view of uiviewcontroller from storyboard or nib files you should override

```
-loadView
```

method to set up view hierarchy. [Read view management section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) This will probably solve your problem with search field. 
To solve second problem set up cellidentifier

```
NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Your identifier";
```

I don't think that it can be nil. 
I hope, my answer will help. If not, just leave a comment.